# How to transform a quadric given its matrix form and an affine transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, linear-transformations, quadrics

I'm trying to follow [these](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Edhouse/courses/405/notes/quadrics.pdf) notes on using the matrix form of a quadric surface in 3D. On page 3, they give an example of starting from the form of a unit sphere at the origin and scaling it up by a factor of 3 in all directions, which all works fine.

However, I then tried my own example. Starting from the same unit sphere and translating it by one unit along the x-axis using the affine transformation matrix

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

and then finding the new Q-matrix which should represent the transformed quadric as

$$ Q' = M^{-1} Q (M^{-1})^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Writing the equation of this quadric as $ x^T Q' x = 0 $ gives $ y^2+z^2+2x-1 = 0 $, which clearly isn't correct because it's not even a sphere but a paraboloid ([graph here](https://www.math3d.org/9aqR1h1gU)).

What's also not helping my confidence here is that I couldn't get WolframAlpha to verify my matrix computation above - [this calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%20%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C-1%7D%7D%20%20%5C%2840%29transpose%5C%2840%29Power%5B%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29) certainly doesn't match mine, but I do think mine is correct and it is not getting the syntax or something.

Can anyone help me do this transformation correctly? What went wrong? It says on page 4 that non-linear transformations (i.e. translations) should still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my issue - turns out I was misusing the formula.

It worked when I used $ Q' = (M^{-1})^T Q M^{-1} $ instead.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the accepted answer.